# Solving for an integer-valued triangle side lengths

Tags: geometry, triangles, solution-verification

> A triangle has sides of following dimensions
>   $7cm$, $17cm$ and third side is an integer. Find the number of triangles possible.

What I did:-
Maximum possible value of third side

As we know, third side will be surely less than the sum of the other two sides. $23<17+7$
Minimum possible value of third side
Difference of any two sides is less than the third side
$11>17-7=10$

Number of possible values between $11$ and $23$ are $13$. But the total number of triangles possible is $33$. How?

This is a gmat exam question.

Comment: You are correct.  There is a typographical error in the answer key.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you told us exactly which book/website you got this problem from, and the question number/page number.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're right; there's probably an error with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be side-length of the third side.

Hence, $7+17>a$ and $7+a>17$, which gives $10<a<24$ or $11\leq a\leq 23$,
which gives the answer: $13$.

I think your book is wrong.